# I keep getting this error on Roblox Studio: Amount is not a valid member of Frame

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

In Roblox Studio, I keep getting this error:  ***Amount is not a valid member of Frame***
How do I fix It
Here is the Code:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local currencyGui = script.Parent
local currencyHolderFrame = currencyGui:FindFirstChild("currencyHolder")
local materialsFrame = currencyHolderFrame:FindFirstChild("Materials")
local coinsFrame = currencyHolderFrame:FindFirstChild("Coins")

repeat wait(1) until player.leaderstats

local function changeValue(name: string, amount: name)
    if name == "Materials" then
        materialsFrame.Amount.Text = amount.."/50"
    elseif name == "Coins" then
        coinsFrame.Amount.Text = amount 
    end
    

end

changeValue("Materials", player.leaderstats.Materials.Value)
changeValue("Coins", player.leaderstats.Coins.Value)

player.leaderstats.Materials.Changed:Connect(function()
    changeValue("Materials", player.leaderstats.Materials.Value)
end)
player.leaderstats.Coins.Changed:Connect(function()
    changeValue("Coins", player.leaderstats.Coins.Value)
end)
```

I tried changing Amount for something else, But It didn't work.

Comment: Do both CoinsFrame and MaterialsFrame have a TextLabel named Amount as a child?

Comment: No, they don't . Thanks for answering my question.